# C++ array with a predefined size as member variable and memory leak

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-leaks

I hope my question is not redundant. I found some posts which were close to my question but it was not exactly the same.

I have a piece of code which look like this:

```
 class myClass
 {
    public:
    myClass(){
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
            myArray[i]=i;
        }
    };
    ~myClass(){};

    int getValue(int index){return myArray[index];}

   private:
        int myArray[1000];
 } ;

int myFunction(myClass* myObject)
{
    int res=0;
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
        res=res+myObject->getValue(i);
    }
    delete myObject;
    myObject = new myClass();
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    myClass *myObject = new myClass();
    int res= myFunction(myObject);

    delete myObject;
    return res;
}
```

Is there any memory leak in my code? or is this ok? I'm not sure how I should handle the array.

Thanks, 
Jules

Comment: Make `int myFunction(myClass* myObject)` `int myFunction(myClass* & myObject)` if you want to create a new myObject and use it in the caller.

Comment: `I'm not sure how I should handle the array.` .. handle what about it specifically? Do you need an explicit array or could you use a `std::vector` or a `std::list` by chance?

Comment: Note that in Unix-land the return value from "main" is reduced modulo 256. So (disregarding the UB elsehwere) the program isn't portable. And in Windows there's a value just above that that you should not ever use, because it means "the process is still running".

Comment: Allocating `myObject` dynamically is unnecessary. Why is that done?

Answer (score 4):

`myObject = new myClass();` only modifies the local pointer inside the function, not the one declared in `main`.

That's why the `myClass` object allocated inside `myFunction` is leaked, and you end up double-deleting the object that the pointer in `main` points to (which is undefined behavior).

This is because pointers are by default passed by copy. If you want the function to modify the pointer in `main`, pass a reference to it:

```
int myFunction(myClass*& myObject)
                       ^
```

Regarding the array, it's an automatic variable. So it's tied to the current stack frame and thus released automatically, you don't have to do anything. If you had allocated the array manually with `new[]`, *only* then would you need to explicitly `delete[]` it.

Comment: Thx for the explantations, it helps a lot!

Answer (score 3):

`myObject` is deleted twice, inside `myFunction` and inside `main`.

It is undefined behavior.

The reason is that the assignment `myObject = new myClass();` inside `myFunction` changes the local variable, not `myObject` variable in `main` (since it is passed by value).

---

If the intention was to re-allocate an object inside `myFunction` and have matching `new`/`delete`, consider passing the pointer by reference:

```
int myFunction(myClass*& myObject)
```

But please also read the comment of **@Cheers and hth. - Alf**

Comment: re "consider passing the pointer by reference", why on Earth (or Mars, or the Moon) would one do that? Hello.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Perhaps too late and I'm missing something. My understanding was that the idea of the exercise is to re-allocate an instance of `myClass` within `myFunction` and get matching `new`s and `delete`s. What did I overlook?

Comment: Nothing in that way. It's just that there's *so much wrong* with this code that ideas about intentions can easily be wrong, and advice can very easily be taken literally. I would instead give advice such as **separate concerns** -- use one function to compute the sum, and another one to reallocate (if the reallocation really is intentional).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Oh, yes, if you read it like that, I agree. I slightly edited the post.

Comment: Thx to both of you for the explantations and advice!